# Find all ideals in the following ring containing an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

Can someone help me find the complete list of proper ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ containing $(x^3+1,6)$? I have been struggling on this for hours. I want to use this to find all ideals of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^3+1,6)}$. Should there be 15?
This is what I have:
$$(x^3+1,6)$$
$$(x+1,6)$$
$$(x^2-x+1,6)$$
$$(x^3+1,3)$$
$$(x^2-x+1,3)$$
$$(x+1,3)$$
$$(x^3+1,2)$$
$$(x^2-x+1,2)$$
$$(x+1,2)$$
$$(x+1,x^2-x+1,2)$$
$$(x+1,x^2-x+1,3)$$
$$(x+1,x^2-x+1,6)$$

Is this right so far? What are the others? This would really help me out. I know that $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^3+1,6)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{(x^3+1)} \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{(x^3+1)}$ but I do not know how this can help me. Is it possible for a principle ideal to be on this list? Can someone explain to me how to use $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^3+1,6)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{(x^3+1)} \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{(x^3+1)}$ to do this? I know the factors of $x^3+1$ are $x+1$ and $x^2-x+1$ so there are $16$ ideals determined by $(1),(x^3+1),(x^2-x+1),(x+1)$ but I cannot figure out how to use this with the primes $2,3$. I know the first $9$ are correct, but I am having trouble determining the others. I tried ideals of the form $(f(x),2,3)$ but I know this generates the whole ring.

Comment: There is a theorem called the Correspondance Theorem that states that you have a bijection between the set of ideals of $R$ that contain some ideal $I$, and the set of ideals of $R/I$, so both sets are the same time. You can use this to calculate the number of ideals you are looking for

Comment: @Evaristo can you help me with that.

Comment: @Evaristo Wouldn't there be $16$ based on the isomorphism I wrote and factors of $x^3+1$?

Comment: @Evaristo Then I would have to find all ideals containing $(x^3+1,6)$ which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^3+1, 6) \equiv (\Bbb{Z}/6\Bbb{Z})[x]/(x^3+1)$. If you find all the ideals in the latter ring (which is finite), you can find all the ideals in the former ring. You need to check which ideals in your list coincide in the finite ring.

Comment: @RobArthan would you say I have most of the ideals, also are the last three ideals?

Comment: Any set of elements of a ring generate an ideal, so all the elements on your list are ideals.

Comment: I would go with the sum, because the ideals of a direct sum are direct sum of ideals, and you can tackle each quotient on its own, which is easier.

Comment: @RobArthan I am looking for distinct ideals which contain $(x^3+1,6)$ and all of them.

Comment: Consider the first one. The number of ideals in it will be the number of ideals in $Z_3[X]$ containing $(x^3+1)$. But now, this is a principal ideal, and it is much easier to think about the ideals containing it

Comment: @Evaristo there are four $(x^3+1),(1),(x+1),(x^2-x+1)$

Comment: @Evaristo can I ask if there are 16 distinct ideals containing $(x^3+1,6)$ based on the isomorphism?

Comment: The set of ideals of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ that contain $(x^3+1, 6)$ is in one-one correspondence with the set of all ideals in $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^3+1, 6)$.

Comment: @RobArthan isn't the set of ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ that contain $(x^3+1,6)$ what I am struggling on? Moreover, that is what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: Sounds right to me, but I don't really have where to write this down at the moment, I would have given a full response otherwise. Good luck with this one, and sorry for not helping much

Comment: Yes. And reducing that set to a corresponding set of ideals in the finite ring $\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^3+1, 6)$ is a big step on the way to answering your question.

Comment: @RobArthan Wouldn't $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^3+1,6)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{(x^3+1)} \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{(x^3+1)}$ and that $x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$ imply there must be $16$ distinct ideals containing $(x^3+1,6)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the ideal correspondence theorem, the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ which contain $(x^3 + 1, 6)$ correspond to the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ in a bijective manner.

So we need to find all the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x] / (x^3 + 1, 6)$. To do this, we will find the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x] / (x^3 + 1) \times \mathbb{Z}_3[x] / (x^3 + 1)$.

Note that over $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$, we have $x^3 + 1 = (x + 1)^3$. So we are analysing the ideals of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x] / ((x + 1) (x^2 + x + 1)) \times \mathbb{Z}_3[x] / ((x + 1)^3)$.

The associate classes of $\mathbb{Z}_3[x] / ((x + 1)^3)$ are therefore $1 \mid (x + 1) \mid (x + 1)^2 \mid(x + 1)^3 = 0$.

And the associate classes of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x] / ((x + 1)(x^2 + x + 1))$ are $1$, $x + 1$, $x^2 + x + 1$, and $(x + 1)(x^2 + x + 1) = 0$. And let us note that $(x + 1, x^2 + x + 1) = (1)$.

In general, the ideals of $R_1 \times R_2$ are of the form $I_1 \times I_2$ where $I_i$ is an ideal in $R_i$.

This gives us 16 distinct ideals of the product ring - an ideal $(a, b)$ for each associate class pairing.

So there are indeed a total of 15 proper ideals.

To translate an ideal back to an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, we must consider the map $f : \mathbb{Z}[x] \to (\mathbb{Z}_2[x] / (x^3 + 1), \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3 + 1))$. We take an ideal $I$ of $\mathbb{Z}_2[x] / (x^3 + 1), \mathbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^3 + 1)$ and take its inverse image $f^{-1}(I)$.

To compute all the ideals, we must first find one solution $f(P) = (x + 1, 1)$ and another for $f(Q) = (x^2 + x + 1, 1)$. We must then find one solution of $f(R) = (1, x + 1)$.

From here, for each $i \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$, each $j \in \{0, 1\}$, and each h $k \in \{0, 1\}$, we have the ideal $(P^j Q^k R^i, x^3 + 1, 6) = f^{-1}(((x + 1)^j (x^2 + x + 1)^k, (x + 1)^i))$.

This method gives us all 16 ideals of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ which contain $6$ and $x^3 + 1$. We then throw out $(1)$ to get the 15 necessary ideals.

Comment: Mark to the rescue.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out:

$$\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^3+1,6)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{(x^3+1)} \oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{(x^3+1)}$$

Now $$\frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{(x^3+1)} \cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{(x+1)}\oplus \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{(x^2+x+1)}\cong \mathbb{F}_2\oplus\mathbb{F}_4,$$

and   $$\frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{(x^3+1)}\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{(x+1)^3}\cong \frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[y]}{(y^3)}.$$

Each field has $2$ ideals, including the whole field, and $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[y]}{(y^3)}$ has $4$ ideals (including itself): $$(1),(y),(y^2),(0).$$

Thus in total you get $2\times 2\times 4=16$ ideals.  However one of these is the ring itself, so you have $15$ proper ideals in total.

---

To actually find these ideals, note that $$3+4=1,\qquad 3^2=3, \qquad4^2=4,\qquad {\rm in}\quad \frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^3+1,6)}.$$  Thus $3\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ represents the identity of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{(x^3+1)}$ and $4\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ represents the identity of $\frac{\mathbb{Z}_3[x]}{(x^3+1)}$.

Thus $$4,\qquad 4(1+x),\qquad 4(1+x)^2$$
represent the generators of the ideals in $\mathbb{Z}_3[y]/{y^3}$.

We have $$(x^2+x+1)-x(x+1)=1.$$

Thus $(x^2+x+1)\in \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{(x^3+1)}$ represents the identity in $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $-x(x+1)\in \frac{\mathbb{Z}_2[x]}{(x^3+1)}$ represents the identity in $\mathbb{F}_4$.

Putting it all together, we obtain all $15$ ideals by:

$(1)$ Starting with $x^3+1,6$.

$(2)$ Adding one of $4, 4(1+x),4(1+x)^2$ or none of them.

$(3)$ Adding $3(x^2+x+1)$ or not.

$(4)$ Adding $-3x(x+1)$ or not.

$(5)$ Throw away the case where you added $4, 3(x^2+x+1), -3x(x+1)$ (as this is not a proper ideal).

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I know the first nine on my list are correct (can you let me know if any of these coincide) can you help me find the others? That is what I am really struggling on.

Comment: @Mauro I have listed the generators of all ideals containing $(1+x^3, 6)$.

Comment: Thanks so much I greatly appreciate it.